# c++ combine singleton and visitor pattern

Tags: c++, pointers, design-patterns, singleton, visitor-pattern

I'm having a problem with pointers. My background is Java and I've still not got the hand of using pointers. 
My error is:

```
syntax error: identifier 'StockController'
```

from this line:

```
virtual void visit(StockController* stock) = 0;
```

I've implemented my singleton. But now i'm looking to add the visitor pattern. I have a series of operations ill be applying to the collection of objects.

**Visitor abstract class:**

```
#ifndef VISITOR_H
#define VISITOR_H

#include "StockController.h"

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(StockController* stock) = 0;
};

#endif
```

**Singleton class:**

```
#ifndef StockController_H
#define StockController_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Visitable.h"

using namespace std;

class StockController : public Visitable {
public:
    /*Returns an instance of the class */
    static StockController* getInstance();

protected:
    /* Prevent initialisation unless through get method */
    StockController();
    StockController(const StockController&);
    StockController& operator= (const StockController&);

private:

    /* Class instance */
    static StockController* _instance;

};

#endif
```

**Visitable.h:**

```
#ifndef VISITABLE_H
#define VISITABLE_H

#include "Visitor.h"

class Visitable {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor &visitor) = 0;

};

#endif
```

Comment: Where is Visitable.h and what line is giving you the error?

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. For which file did the compiler report the error you mentioned?

Comment: Make sure `Visitable.h` does not include `Visitor.h` otherwise you have a circular include which there are 1000s of duplicates on this site.

Comment: Your code is pointer-infested. That's precisely because of your Java background, where pointers are necessary for every instance of a custom type. In C++, you are supposed to use *references* when you can and pointers when you have to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve circular dependencies in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Comment: Removing `Visitor.h` from `Visitor.h` generated additional errors. Since i'm using a `Visitor` object as a parameter of the accept method.

Comment: Use a forward declaration to remove the circular dependency. Please read and understand what a circular dependency is.

Comment: In `Visitable.h` put `class Visitor;` where you have `#include "Visitor.h"`

Comment: Thank you. So I was looking in the wrong place.